Unable to build react native app on ios due to flipperkit
I am using React Native (0.73.2) and the app builds for android without issue. I am now at a stage where I am trying to test and build for ios however the build fails and this is the only information I have:
The following build commands failed:
        CompileC /Users/user257599/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/###-cagfttfeertkgidamqciuaveliuz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FlipperKit.build/Objects-normal/arm64/FlipperPlatformWebSocket.o /Users/user257599/Documents/###/###/ios/Pods/FlipperKit/iOS/FlipperKit/FlipperPlatformWebSocket.mm normal arm64 objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'FlipperKit' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)

I really have no idea where to go from here. I have tried running pod update with no success

Can you post your Podfile please?

You can simply comment the :flipper_configuration => flipper_config like this
 use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # Enables Flipper.
    #
    # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
    # you should disable the next line.
    # :flipper_configuration => flipper_config,
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )


after that run pod update inside ios folder.
